# symfony2 form change password

Tags: symfony

I'm trying to make a modified form of an employee but I have a problem with the password field.

When I'm on the form if not insert anything in the password that is modified with a blank password. This is not correct and I want that if the user does nothing with the password does not get the password blank.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that you're using one field to hold two different things: a plain password and its hash. So, instead, split them into `$plainPassword` and `$password` and update the `$password` field only if the `$plainPassword` is not empty:

```php
if ($plainPassword = $user->getPlainPassword()) {
    $encoder  = $this->get('security.encoder_factory')->getEncoder($user);
    $password = $encoder->encodePassword($plainPassword, $user->getSalt());
    $user->setPassword($password);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just do not update password field if it's not submitted(modified).
I think that's all you need

```
/**
* @ORM\Entity
**/
class User 
{
   // your setters/getters

   public function setPassword($password) 
   {
       if (null === $password)  {
           return; 
       }

       $this->password = $password;
   }
}
```